# Tamaño de Datos sqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me esta dando un error en un procedimiento almacenado que me dice q la longitud de los datos LOB (10 0543) que se vana replicar supera al maximo configurado (65 536).

Answer (score 1):

**Los siguientes pasos deben realizarse:**

1. Ir a SQL Server Management Studio
2. Haga clic derecho en un servidor y seleccione Propiedades
3. Seleccione Propiedades
4. Ir a la página avanzada
5. Cambiar el tamaño de la replicación de texto máximo a cualquier valor que desee